# What do "before going in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context link:https://www.quora.com/Is-drowning-a-painful-way-to-die/answer/RetchedRevolver

> I also have to say that the way you breathe and hold your breath beforehand completely differentiates the experience; if you breathe in through your lungs and not your diaphragm **before going in**, your last moments are typically far more euphoric.

The `before going in` to my mind as "XX go into a YY(container)", is this meaning `before water going in your lung`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are XX and YY is the body of water, I think.

Before [they] go in [the water].

By the way, weird subject matter.